# ResponseError: Unauthorized sendgrid

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

I keep getting 401 unauthorized, could send email as of yesterday, then it started giving me the error

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail')
const aikey = 'SG.GCxxxxxxxxxxxxw.vMxxxxxxxxxvxxxxxxxxxxxM'
sgMail.setApiKey(aikey)

const msg = {
  to: 'test@example.com', // Change to your recipient
  from: 'test@example.com', // Change to your verified sender
  subject: 'Sending with SendGrid is Fun',
  text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
}

sgMail
  .send(msg)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response[0].statusCode)
    console.log(response[0].headers)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
  })
```

The error 401

```
ResponseError: Unauthorized
    at C:\Users\kennedy\Documents\try personalization\node_modules\@sendgrid\client\src\classes\client.js:146:29
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  code: 401,
  response: {
    headers: {
      server: 'nginx',
      date: 'Wed, 27 Jul 2022 08:22:58 GMT',
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'content-length': '76',
      connection: 'close',
      'access-control-allow-origin': 'https://sendgrid.api-docs.io',
      'access-control-allow-methods': 'POST',
      'access-control-allow-headers': 'Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl',      'access-control-max-age': '600',
      'x-no-cors-reason': 'https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=600; includeSubDomains'
    },
    body: { errors: [Array] }
  }
}
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

I am using a sendgrid free plan, can it be the reason?

Comment: In the error you can see `body: { errors: [Array] }`, if you log just the `body` then you will be able to see those errors and it will tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Do you replace this part of code with actual email in 'to' and 'from'
section ?

```
const msg = {
  to: 'test@example.com', // Change to your recipient
  from: 'test@example.com', // Change to your verified sender
  subject: 'Sending with SendGrid is Fun',
  text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
}
```